# Recompiling and running a decompiled MCP minecraft client throws a noSuchMethod error

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So in the past days i've decompiled minecraft 1.12.2 using mcp to make an "own" client. I ran it from eclipse and all was working just fine. But once i exported it, added the needed JSON file and started it from the minecraft launcher, it resulted the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Client thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.info(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:420)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:115)
```

In my opinion that'a a bit strange, because when I ran it from eclipse that error did NOT occur.
I was thinking about adding the logger in the specific JSON file for the version but I do not know how to do it. I took the JSON file from a video where I expected my problem to be solved, made some changes, but it didn't. I also put the folder containing the logger-jar (org.apache....) in the client jar, but still no success.
Also i just decompiled 1.12.2 and recompiled it right away to see if i had messed up my code some how.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Have you checked your ``classpath`` to see that log4j is being found correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This means at runtime you have a class that is different than what you had at compile time. You should try unzipping the jar and searching for the class file. It sounds like you need to potentially remove it and replace it with your own version.

Comment: So, I took all folders out of the api.jar and put them into my src folder (org.apache.logging.log4j) but the class files don't show up. So I deleted them and put them in my Client.jar AFTER the export. Now there IS a method org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.info() but I still get stuck with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all who viewed an wanted to help!
Now I found an other way to use it. I wanted to export it to test
it on my server. But instead I used my account credentials to log in directly from eclipse.
:)